# Meteorjs Foundation modals events freezes the browser

Tags: javascript, meteor, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I add foundation 4 to my meteor web. I use this package

```
https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/foundation
```

I follow the steps on the foundation main page [Foundation 4](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html)

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
  <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
  <p>Im a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

And I add the link

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" class="open radius button">Example Modal…</a>
```

The modal opens correctly, but when I try to close the modal the browser is frozen. I tested add other events to the modal, like a link that just do a console log, and is frozen too. Looks like I cant use events inside the modal... any idea on how to close the modal and add events to it ??

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting the modal in a template?

```
<head>
  <title>foundation</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> foundation}}
</body>

<template name="foundation">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
        <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
        <p>Im a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>

    <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" class="open radius button">Example Modal…</a>
</template>
```

That close button seems to be working for me when done this way.

And if you need to listen for events on the modal you can just specify one or more event handlers in your client code:

```
// foundation.js - foundation is the name of my meteor project
// so this is the default file added to my project
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.foundation.events({
    "click h2": function(e) {
      console.log("modal h2 clicked");
    }
  });

  Template.foundation.rendered = function() {
    // you can bind custom events here if you need to
  }
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Comment: Word of warning, if your ".reveal-modal" isn't inserted directly under the <body> tag then Foundation will [make a copy](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js#L254) of the element before displaying is which means the Meteor events won't be bound to it. So make sure you modal element is defined as a first-child of your <body> tag to avoid problems.